# remove_cart_item removing items from bundles

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce Product bundles plugin and when I validate cart via filter  'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation' I delete individual items that are in cart through WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($cart_item_key). But it removes bundled items too. How do I keep remove_cart_item from affecting bundled items?

Answer (score 0):

Self answer, just ensure cart item has ['bundled_items'] set before running remove_cart_item.